# How to prevent tar extraction from overwriting symbolic links directories

Tags: linux, bash, unix, tar, centos7

Note:Overwriting of the symlinks occurs from tar version 1.27 or higher

Below I am trying to show what exactly the problem is.

contents of the dirtmp1

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
```

code to create the above directory

```
rm -f -r dirtmp1 && mkdir dirtmp1 && cd dirtmp1 && touch file1.txt && touch file2.txt && ls -al
```

creating a symbolic link

```
cd ..
ln -s dirtmp1/ symlink1
```

now create the tar file which contains the name as symlink1

```
mkdir dirtmp1
cd dirtmp1
mkdir symlink1 && cd symlink1 && touch iNeedThisfile.txt && cd .. && tar -cvzf symlink1.tar.gz symlink1/
```

Extract the tar file in folder(symlnk1) is overwriting the symbolic link. All I want is preserve the symbolic link and copy the "iNeedThisfile.txt"

After running this command `tar -xvf symlink1.tar.gz`

`symlink1:
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 24 18:14 iNeedThisfile.txt`

Any flags while extracting which preserves the symbolic links while extracting. and copies the files to the folder pointed by the symbolic link.

I apologise for not able to convey my message in fewer lines of text.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't working? This worked for me on a CentOS 5 machine.

Comment: you want extact one file from tar file ? `tar -xvf {symlink1.tar.gz} {path/to/file}`

Comment: @Etan Reisner no it is is not working on centos 7 , tar version 1.26

Comment: @Hidd3n I do not want to extract single file, but while extracting do not want to override the symbolic link to the file.

Comment: Why u extract tar to another path that not exit symbolic link file?

Comment: @Hidd3n I did not get that

Comment: I means extract tar file to another place has not exit symbolic link when you extract no replace happened

Comment: @Hidd3n That can be the case , but I want to extract on the same place and this worked earlier in tar version 1.20 no longer from tar version 1.27

Comment: Does using the `-k` flag to tar change anything? (I can try this on a CentOS 7 machine later.)

Comment: @EtanReisner using the k flag will not overwrite the existing files and reports an error back.  I want to overwrite the existing files in my case

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem. In my case, tar 1.23 had the proper behavior (preserved the symbolic link) while 1.26 had the "new" behavior (deleted the symbolic link and created a directory instead).

I found adding the -h flag to the tar on the EXTRACT does the job. The symbolic link is preserved and the file(s) are added to the directory it points to.

E.g., I had to go from

```
tar zxf foo.tar.gz
```

to

```
tar -h -zxf foo.tar.gz
```

Comment: @Brain Thanks so much for replying, I read the documentation but missed this -h flag. I will try this :)

Comment: Added -h flag did not work for me in tar version 1.26. Centos 7. Extracting the contents removes the symlink :(

Comment: Works for REHL 7. That piece of sh*t threw 2 days of frustration on me. +1

Comment: I don't know which OS it works, but I'm with @forum.test17 -- it is not working in my Debian, tar 1.30+dfsg-6 as we speak. Extracting the contents using `tar -h -zxf` removes the symlink for me too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Debian and the answer provided by Brian doesn't work for me. Rereading the OP again, I now realized that the OP want to preserve symlink *of a directory*, whereas I want to preserve the symlink *of each individual files*. But since this is the only hit I found on this, and since I've already typed out my answer, I'll provide it anyway, for preserving the symlink of each individual files.

So here is the solution that I found out.

First of all, my Debian as we speak:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:        10
Codename:       buster
```

and my tar is 1.30+dfsg-6:

```
$ apt-cache policy tar
tar:
  Installed: 1.30+dfsg-6
  Candidate: 1.30+dfsg-6
  Version table:
 *** 1.30+dfsg-6 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

What I found is,

- `tar -h -xvf symlink1.tar.gz` will not work. Extracting the contents this way will remove the symlinks. `tar -h --no-overwrite-dir -xvf symlink1.tar.gz` will not work either. But,
- `tar -h --overwrite -xvf symlink1.tar.gz` will work! Extracting the contents this way will keep the symlinks of each individual files, But,
- `tar -h --overwrite -xvJf symlink1.tar.xz` will not work. I.e., what works for `.tar.gz` will not work for `.tar.xz` files.

HTH for anyone wanting to preserve the symlink of each individual files.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is `--keep-directory-symlink`.  (I believe that `-h` only applies to *creating* tar files.)

This option has been in Gnu `tar` [for almost 10 years](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/tar.git/commit/?id=2c06a80918019471876956eef4ef22f05c9e0571), but I think Ubuntu only started exposing it in 20.04/focal (the 18.04 man page does not mention the option).

Aside: What's really weird for me is that I only needed to use `--keep-directory-symlink` **when I ran the command remotely via SSH** (e.g. `ssh [host] "tar xzvf tarball-with-unsymlinked-directory-paths.tgz"`).  When I extracted the *same tarball* directly in a local interactive login session on the same machine I did not need `--keep-directory-symlink`. No idea why. (This is on an Ubuntu 22.04 system.) It seems Ubuntu's `tar` is not quite the standard Gnu `tar`.